# I am getting this message: Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_action()

Tags: php, function, action

I am no expert on Wordpress. I accidentally made an adjustment to a `Function.php` file on the editor of my theme and that automatically created a 500Error, I was able to enable the DEBUG on my theme to find out where the error is and I am now getting this:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_action() in /home/collabis/public_html/wp/wp-includes/functions.php on line 343

The only thing I have tried is to upload the original theme's `function.php` file directly through `Cpanel` but nothing's happening. I am unsure what else to do. Some people mentioned replacing the funtion.php is the one within the theme, so I did that.

Any thoughts?

Comment: First rename the function.php file and check. If your site still running with the error, then upload the original function.php file, clear the site and browser cache and check.

Comment: `add_action()` is a WordPress function. A pretty important one too. It is supposed to be defined in `wp-includes/plugins.php`, but if you are missing it, either that file is gone, or it's not being imported somehow. Are you able to use FTP or SSH to login to your server and navigate the directories?

Comment: what plugin is it calling? How do I edit that? Yes, I can access Cpanel through the browser, I just can't access to the Wordpress admin.